# To whom static int Main return value?

Tags: c#

I have written a program by changing void to int

```
class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        return -1;
    }        
}
```

To whom this value will get return ...is it CLR? If so, how... because a called function can return a value to a calling function.

If this is the called function, then who is the calling function..is it CLR?
How it is happening ?

Does CLR returns any value to someone, e.g. OS?

Comment: calling process. e.g. cmd, or whatever. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: To the operating system.  From whence it can be retrieved with, say, Process.ExitCode in a .NET program or the GetExitCodeProcess() winapi function or %errorlevel% in a batch file.  Also look in the VS Output window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If this is the called function, then who is the calling function..is
>   it CLR? How it is happening ?

The `Main` method is called by the `CLR`. How is this happpening?

Initially, windows examines the exe's file's header to determine whether to create a 32-bit process or a 64-bit process, or a WoW64 process.

Then windows loads the x86, x64, or IA64 version of MSCorEE.dll into process's address space.

After this, the process's primary thread calls a method defined inside MSCorEE.dll. This method initializes the CLR, loads the exe assembly, and then calls its entry point method `Main`.

The method `Main` can return nothing, `void` or and `int`. If we choose to return an `int`, then usually we select to return 0, at the end of `Main`, which means that the execution of the Program was successful. If `Main` return another negative `int`, then we have an error. Both of them are conventions that are used widely.

That being said, it is clear that the value that `Main` returns is returned to the process's primary thread.

**Update**

How we could read this value?

We could build a batch file that will execute our executable. (I have given it the name `ExecutableName`, you should change it correspondingly.) We can read the value that Main returns using the %ERRORLEVEL%. If it is not 0, then the message `Failed with error code` with the corresponding error value will be printed to the screen.

```
@echo off
ExecutableName.exe

IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto error

echo OK
goto end

:error
echo Failed with error code %ERRORLEVEL%.

:end
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to detail it more (:

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar sure thing. Actually, if it something misses is that DrKoch says in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile this piece of code it will produce a .exe program.
This is called by the operating system.
The return value will be passed back to the operating system when your program terminates.

You can use this return value for example in a batch script (*.bat) by observing %ERRORLEVEL%

If you start your .exe from another .Net program using the Process class, you'll find this return value in Process.ExitCode after your .exe has finished.